# How to handle the length of text box to fit on one subplot in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add the following text on just the first subplot of a figure.

```
txt = "NY Fed WEI is an index of ten daily and weekly indicators of real economic activity:Initial unemployment isurance claims; continuing unemployment insurance claims; federal taxes with-held; Redbook same-store sales; Rasmussen consumer index; American Staffing Assoc. Staffing Index; raw steel production; US railroad traffic; US fuel sales to end users; US electricity output"

ax.annotate(txt, xy=(0, 1), xycoords='axes fraction' ,xytext=(-5, 5), textcoords='offset points',ha='left', va='top', **{'fontsize':'x-small', 'wrap':True})
```

[image]

I want the entire text just on the first subplot i.e. under US GDP and doesn't want that to extend across to the other subplot i.e. US Business Investment. I have used the following code as well but even that gives similar results.

```
ax.text(0, 0.7, txt, ha='left', va='top', wrap=True, fontsize=5, transform=ax.transAxes, bbox=dict(boxstyle='square', fc='w'))
```

Is there any way to put the text like in the following figure on a single subplot?
[image]

Comment: I looked for a way to solve this issue and found one approach. Please refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079364/wrapping-text-not-working-in-matplotlib). I also tried to run it, but I found a secondary issue where setting `_get_wrap_line_width` reduced the graph size. `txt = ax1.text(mdates.date2num(data.index[0]), 145, txt, ha='left', va='top', wrap=True, bbox=dict(boxstyle='square', fc='w'));txt._get_wrap_line_width = lambda : 350. `

Comment: Thanks. The following worked for me: 
`text = ax.text(0, 0.9, txt, ha='left', va='top', wrap=True, fontsize=5, transform=ax.transAxes)
text._get_wrap_line_width = lambda : 250.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `_get_wrap_line_width` to define the line width. The following worked for me:

```
text = ax.text(0, 0.9, txt, ha='left', va='top', wrap=True, fontsize=5, transform=ax.transAxes)
text._get_wrap_line_width = lambda : 250.
```

Its important to use `transform=ax.transAxes` to put everything on the axes instead of figure.